# Spring Session generates a new JSESSIONID with every request

Tags: tomcat, spring-session

I am using Spring Session 1.3.5.
The problem is that it is creating a new JSESSIONID for every HTTP request. I have noticed that this kicks-in before the response is committed by the filter's method below.

org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper#onResponseCommitted

Does anybody know how to configure spring session (with XML) to only create a new session if it is necessary?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

L